# How to install and use browserify in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

I cant find any tutorial about install and use browerify in ExpressJS. Hope someone here can help.

Comment: Did you try to google it? The first link from Google search [Using Browserify with Express](https://makerlog.org/posts/express-and-browserify)

Answer (score 0):

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Express](http://expressjs.com/) are in no way related - It's like apples and ... monkeys.

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is used on client-side for dependency injection and bundling of your javascript source code. (using `require`)

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a server-side web framework module for [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can install "browserify" using the following command

```
npm install browserify
```

I will recommend it to install globally with the following command.

```
npm install -g browserify
```

To get more idea about how to use it, you should go through the "BUNDLE UP YOUR FIRST MODULE" section of its documentation. http://browserify.org/